# Error: OOM when allocating tensor with shape

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, gunicorn

i am facing issue with my inception model during the performance testing with Apache JMeter.

> Error: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[800,1280,3] and type
>   float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator
>   GPU_0_bfc      [[Node: Cast = CastDstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_UINT8,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>   Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens,
>   add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current
>   allocation info.

Answer (score 24):

OOM stands for Out Of Memory.  That means that your GPU has run out of space, presumably because you've allocated other tensors which are too large.  You can fix this by making your model smaller or reducing your batch size.  By the looks of it, you're feeding in a large image (800x1280) you may want to consider downsampling.

Comment: I'm getting this error on the 4th epoch of training. Epochs 1-3 succeeded. Do you know why this would occur? The memory demands on the GPU during epoch 4 are the same as the memory demands during the first 3 epochs. Am I supposed to be releasing GPU memory after each batch is processed or something like that?

Comment: You might be creating more tensors in the training loop which would cause more memory to be consumed, you shouldn't be doing that.  It's hard to say without the code though.

Comment: What is the best way to ensure that unused tensor are deleted or the best way to ensure that more tensors aren't been created in the training loop as you suggested @CoryNezin

Comment: I am trapped in same error, what is answer to the above thought ? "What is the best way to ensure that unused tensor are deleted or the best way to ensure that more tensors aren't been created in the training loop as you suggested" @CoryNezin

Comment: I haven't used TensorFlow in a while but I'm sure it's been updated with many capabilities since this question.  You might want to ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple GPUS at hand, kindly select a GPU which is not as busy as this one, (possible reasons, other processes are also running on this GPU). Go to terminal and type

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1
```

where 1 is the number of other GPU available. re-run the same code.

you can check the available GPUs using

```
nvidia-smi
```

this will show you what GPUs are available and how much memory is available on each one of them